# is https ssl recommended even though both apps are in private network?

Tags: security, ssl, https

If there are two applications communicating using webservices over http, is it recommended to use ssl even though the hostname:port are not external facing?

If it  can be reasonably guarunteed that no external calls will reach this app, why would we still need to use ssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL (and HTTPS, which is basically HTTP over SSL) stops *all* snooping between client and server when correctly configured. Snoopers can be inside your organization as well as outside of it. Yeah, the internal people shouldn't be doing that, but it *does* happen and it isn't wise to rely on just the network configuration from protecting you.

But you don't need to spend a lot on this! You can use an internal Certificate Authority (OpenSSL includes all the software you need, even if the documentation and interface leave much to be desired) and very few internal apps need to scale out much, so you probably don't need any special hardware like random number sources. Securing a server is such a small amount of work, and such a small amount of intrusion on legitimate users, that there is no excuse not to.

Remember, you should never apply just one layer of security. Apply many! SSL. Firewalls. Network separation. Logging. Each protects against different types of problem and attacker.

Comment: @donal_fellows thanks for answer. So should certificate to be used be different than the one used on regular external facing apps?